# Mixing memory-aligned and unaligned code

Tags: gcc, memory-alignment, blas, compiler-flags

I recently compiled GotoBLAS2 (MacOSX 10.6) and linked it to my code, leading to all kind of wrong results. I ran everything through valgrind noticing some illegal reads from the GotoBLAS. When looking at it more carefully I found that the GotoBLAS is compiled with the -m128bit-long-double alignment option. As soon as I did compile my code with this flag as well (although I don't use any long doubles at all) everything works, giving correct results without any valgrind obscurities.

Now my question ist:

- Do I have to compile all other library dependencies using the same alignment flag?